# Left Menu Jquery Toggle is not working in React JS

Tags: jquery, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

Im trying to create a left menu sidebar in my website using bootstrap and jquery toggle. But in React JS , its not acceptig jquery files kindly please help me to fix this problem, Code as below..Please help me how to fix this issue either by using jquery in my code or by using react js in my website..

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Navbar, Nav, NavItem, NavDropdown, MenuItem} from 'react-bootstrap';

class Pioneer extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>

      <div className="wrapper">

            <nav id="sidebar">
                <div className="sidebar-header">
                    <h3>Bootstrap Sidebar</h3>
                    <strong>BS</strong>
                </div>

                <ul className="list-unstyled components">
                    <li className="active">
                        <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                            <i className="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i>
                            Home
                        </a>
                        <ul className="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
                            <li><a href="#">Home 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Home 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Home 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <i className="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase"></i>
                            About
                        </a>
                        <a href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                            <i className="glyphicon glyphicon-duplicate"></i>
                            Pages
                        </a>
                        <ul className="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu">
                            <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <i className="glyphicon glyphicon-link"></i>
                            Portfolio
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <i className="glyphicon glyphicon-paperclip"></i>
                            FAQ
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <i className="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></i>
                            Contact
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <ul className="list-unstyled CTAs">
                    <li><a href="https://bootstrapious.com/tutorial/files/sidebar.zip" className="download">Download source</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://bootstrapious.com/p/bootstrap-sidebar" className="article">Back to article</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>


            <div id="content">

                <nav className="navbar navbar-default">
                    <div className="container-fluid">

                        <div className="navbar-header">
                            <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" className="btn btn-info navbar-btn">
                                <i className="glyphicon glyphicon-align-left"></i>
                                <span>Toggle Sidebar</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>

                        <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                            <ul className="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                <li><a href="#">Page</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Page</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Page</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Page</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>

                <h2>Collapsible Sidebar Using Bootstrap 3</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

                <div className="line"></div>

                <h2>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

                <div className="line"></div>

                <h2>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

                <div className="line"></div>

                <h3>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Pioneer;
```

Comment: Try putting a CodePen or something together so people can help you better. It is not fully clear what help you need.

Comment: Yeah Sure  #trainoasis

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zJWXrq Here is the codepen kindly help me with this

Comment: What's JS code doing in plain HTML without script tags?